# Tom's family how to cross the bridge

Tags: graphs-and-networks

A interesting question.Tom's family just have a flashlight which will extinguish after 30 seconds.They wanna go through a bridge to arrive opposite side with the flashlight.But as the picture,they need difference time to cross it alone.And a solw man with a faster man,the time depend on that slow man.The bridge only can bear two people at a time.They should how to cross it,then the time will be shortest?How to use method of graphs-and-networks to solve it?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the issue it raises is not a  _Mathematica_ issue but a mathematical one. That it is formulated in terms of _Mathematica_ is not sufficient to make it an appropriate question for _Mathematica_.SE.

Comment: @m_goldberg Confusion of the strict criterion about `Mathematica` and `Mathematical`

Comment: It's often a gray area, but in this case I think you asking for help with the logic of solving the problem much more than how to implement it in _Mathematica_. Others, may disagree with my assessment. If so, the question won't be closed.

Comment: Oh I konw what you have say,I'll edit it in a right way

Comment: Bridge and Torch Problem. There are plenty of descriptions of solution algorithms out there. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_and_torch_problem

Comment: @Quantum_Oli Actually I have the answer of this question.I just wanna use `Mathematica` to implement it.

Comment: My thinking is that each node should consist of the 1 or 2 people you're taking across, not of just one person. And it's always better to have the faster person return the torch, so you could add that into the edge time, except for the final crossing. But I may be missing quite a few things by suggesting this.

Comment: Have a look [Bridge crossing puzzle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144207/bridge-crossing-puzzle)

Comment: Your link goes to ugly hideousness of a page. (OP)

Comment: @barrycarter Ugly?Then I'll cancel the link.That's a original problem.I just translate into English here.

Comment: @Louis I'm in study Green Theory now.I just wanna solve it with `mma` by `Graph`.

Comment: @barrycarter Thanks yor suggestions.:)

Comment: @Yode Oh, I thought you had mislinked. The link is in a foreign language and just appears to be a random website. I didn't realize it was the problem in a different language.

Comment: I'm working on a graph-like solution at https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/STACK/bc-bridge-torch.m if anyone wants to help.

Comment: @barrycarter I have update a new method for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the help with many people in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137571/how-to-repeat-the-nonblank-string),I solve this proble with *Graph Theory* method.Build all possible in a graph based on the costed time on people:

```
time = {1, 3, 6, 8, 12};
people = StringReplace[ToString[time], " " -> ""];
seq[n_ /; n > 1] := Reverse[Riffle[Range[0, n - 2], Range[2, n]]]
Clear[exsited];
exsited[_] = False;
postfix = 
  Rest[If[exsited[#], StringJoin[ToString[#], ToString[Unique[]]], 
       exsited[#] = True; ""] & /@ seq[Length[time]]] //. {a___, 
     p : Except["", _String], "", b___} :> {a, p, p, b};
graphs = Function[{before, behind}, 
    Graph[First[
      WeaklyConnectedGraphComponents[
       RelationGraph[
        Equal[Length[#1], before] && Equal[Length[#2], behind] && 
          SubsetQ @@ SortBy[{##}, -Length[#] &] &, Subsets[time]]]], 
     VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> 400]] @@@ 
   Subsequences[seq[Length[time]], {2}];
Graph[graph = 
  GraphUnion @@ 
   MapThread[
    VertexReplace, {graphs, 
     Apply[If[
        ToString[Length[#1]] === Quiet[First[StringSplit[#2, "$"]]], 
        Rule[#1, 
         StringReplace[StringJoin[{ToString[#1], #2}], " " -> ""]], 
        Rule[#1, StringReplace[ToString[#1], " " -> ""]]] &, 
      Tuples /@ 
       Transpose[{VertexList /@ graphs, List /@ postfix}], {2}]}], 
 VertexLabels -> 
  Table[i -> First[StringSplit[i, RegularExpression["\\d+?\\$"]]], {i,
     VertexList[graph]}], GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"]
```

[image]

#### Find one possible shortest path in graph with `FindShortestPath`.

```
weighGraph = 
  Graph[EdgeList[graph], 
   EdgeWeight -> 
    Table[i -> 
      Quiet[Max[
        Complement @@ 
         SortBy[ToExpression[
             First[StringSplit[#, RegularExpression["\\d+?\\$"]]]] & /@
            List @@ i, -Length[#] &]]], {i, EdgeList[graph]}], 
   EdgeLabels -> Placed["EdgeWeight", 1/4], VertexLabels -> "Name"];
path = FindShortestPath[weighGraph, people, "{}"];
HighlightGraph[graph, Subgraph[weighGraph, path], 
 EdgeLabels -> (Rule @@@ 
    Transpose[{#, 
        Style[ToString[PropertyValue[{weighGraph, #}, EdgeWeight]], 
           Bold, Medium, Darker@Green, 18] & /@ #} &@
      EdgeList@Subgraph[weighGraph, path]]), 
 VertexLabels -> 
  Map[Rule[#, 
     Style[StringReplace[
       First[StringSplit[#, RegularExpression["\\d+?\\$"]]], {"{" -> 
         "", "}" -> ""}], Bold, Medium, Blue, 18]] &, path], 
 GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick", 
 GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"]
```

[image]

As you can see,the cost time is $3 + 1 + 12 + 3 + 3 + 1 + 6=29(minute)$.

#### Find all shortest path.

If we want to find all path,we can use `FindPath` to do it,and select that path shortest.

```
allPath = 
  MinimalBy[FindPath[weighGraph, people, "{}", Infinity, All], 
   Total[PropertyValue[{weighGraph, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ 
      EdgeList@Subgraph[weighGraph, #]] &];
HighlightGraph[graph, Subgraph[weighGraph, #], 
   EdgeLabels -> (Rule @@@ 
      Transpose[{#, 
          Style[ToString[PropertyValue[{weighGraph, #}, EdgeWeight]], 
             Bold, Medium, Darker@Green, 18] & /@ #} &@
        EdgeList@Subgraph[weighGraph, #]]), 
   VertexLabels -> 
    Map[Rule[#, 
       Placed[Style[
         StringReplace[
          First[StringSplit[#, 
            RegularExpression["\\d+?\\$"]]], {"{" -> "", "}" -> ""}], 
         Bold, Medium, Blue, 18], Center]] &, #], 
   GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick", 
   GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", 
   ImageSize -> 320] & /@ allPath
```

[image]

As you can see,all the shortest path is $29(minute)$j,and the green number is time of every step cost.

Answer (score 13):

A variant of the graph solution. I represent the flashlight as a sixth "person" with a crossing time of zero.

```
v = With[{s = Subsets[{0, 1, 3, 6, 8, 12}]}, Transpose[{Reverse@s, s}]];

f[{L1_, R1_}, {L2_, R2_}] := cross[R2 ⋂ L1, L2 ⋂ R1]

cross[LtoR : {0, Repeated[_, 2]}, {}] := Max[LtoR]
cross[{}, RtoL : {0, Repeated[_, 2]}] := Max[RtoL]
cross[__] := Infinity

g = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[v, Outer[f, v, v, 1]];

GraphDistance[g, First@v, Last@v]
(* 29. *)

Grid[FindShortestPath[g, First@v, Last@v], Alignment -> {{Right, Left}}]
```

[image]

**Brief explanation**

- `v` is the list of vertices for the graph, it contains every possible way of splitting the six people (actually five people plus one flashlight) between the two sides of the bridge.
- `f` takes two such vertices and works out who must cross from left to right, and who from right to left, to change from the first configuration to the second. For example `R2 ⋂ L1` is the set of people who are on the right side in configuration 2 and on the left side in configuration 1 - these people must cross from left to right.
- `cross` returns the crossing time for a step, which will be the edge weight in the graph. The allowed steps consist of one or two people plus the flashlight crossing in one direction, and nobody crossing in the other direction. Any other step is forbidden and gets an infinite time.
- The graph is constructed from its weighted adjacency matrix, i.e. the result of applying `f` to each pair of vertices.
- The solution is the shortest path from the first configuration `{{0, 1, 3, 6, 8, 12}, {}}` to the last `{{}, {0, 1, 3, 6, 8, 12}}`

Comment: I am getting a wonderful education from your answers. Thanks! +1 :)

Comment: So inspiring!If you can add some explaination,it will be better.:)

Comment: Could you draw the graph?

Comment: @barrycarter just evaluate g, then you see the graph.

Comment: Have problem when two men with the same speed, maybe caused by `Intersection`.

Answer (score 8):

Without graphs ... I don't see an easy way with them:

```
a = {1, 3, 6, 8, 12};
b = {};

go[{a_, b_, t_, c_}] := ({Complement[a, #], Join[b, #], t + Max@#, Append[c, #]} &/@ 
                                                                     Subsets[a, {2}])

ret[{a_, b_, t_, c_}] := {Join[a, #], Complement[b, #], t + Max@#, Append[c, #]} &/@
                                                                      Subsets[b, {1}]


gf[x_] := Flatten[go /@ x, 1];
rf[x_] := Flatten[ret /@ x, 1];

res = gf@rf@gf@rf@gf@rf[go /@ {{a, b, 0, {}}} // First];

Select[res, #1[[3]] <= 30 &][[All,3;;]]

(*
{{29, {{1, 3}, {1}, {6, 1}, {3}, {8, 12}, {1}, {3, 1}}}, 
 {29, {{1, 3}, {1}, {6, 1}, {1}, {8, 12}, {3}, {1, 3}}}, 
 {29, {{1, 3}, {1}, {8, 12}, {3}, {1, 6}, {1}, {3, 1}}}, 
 {29, {{1, 3}, {1}, {8, 12}, {3}, {1, 3}, {1}, {6, 1}}}, 
 {29, {{1, 3}, {3}, {8, 12}, {1}, {3, 1}, {1}, {6, 1}}}, 
 {29, {{1, 3}, {3}, {8, 12}, {1}, {6, 1}, {1}, {3, 1}}},
 {29, {{1, 6}, {1}, {3, 1}, {3}, {8, 12}, {1}, {3, 1}}},
 {29, {{1, 6}, {1}, {3, 1}, {1}, {8, 12}, {3}, {1, 3}}}}
*)
```

Comment: Good solution.Just didn't use graph.:)

Answer (score 7):

Here you have it solved by using graph functions. I don't think you gain anything by doing it this way

```
a = {1, 3, 6, 8, 12}; int = Intersection; len = Length;
validTransitionFwd[{a_, _}, {x_, _}]  :=  len@a - len@x == 2 && int[a, x] == x
validTransitionBkwd[{a_, _}, {x_, _}] :=  len@x - len@a == 1 && int[a, x] == a
transCost[{s1_, s2_}] := Max[Complement @@@ Transpose@{s1, s2}]

sa = Subsets[Flatten[{#, Reverse@#}&/@ ({Complement[a, #], #} & /@ Subsets@a), 1], {2}];

transitionsFwd = Thread[{{f, b}, #}] & /@ Select[sa, validTransitionFwd @@ # &];
transitionsBwd = Thread[{{b, f}, #}] & /@ Select[sa, validTransitionBkwd @@ # &];

g = Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ #, EdgeWeight -> transCost /@ #[[All, All, 2]]] &@
                                        Union[transitionsBwd, transitionsFwd]

FindShortestPath[g, {f, {{1, 3, 6, 8, 12}, {}}}, {b, {{}, {1, 3, 6, 8,  12}}}][[All, 2]]
(* 
{{{1, 3, 6, 8, 12}, {}}, 
 {{6, 8, 12},       {1, 3}}, 
 {{1, 6, 8, 12},    {3}},
 {{1, 6},           {3, 8, 12}},
 {{1, 3, 6},        {8, 12}},
 {{6},              {1, 3, 8, 12}},
 {{1, 6},           {3, 8, 12}},
 {{},               {1, 3, 6, 8, 12}}}
*)
```

Comment: It seems my original request are little sharp..

Comment: Could you draw the graph?

Comment: @barrycarter ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6n2ey.png)

Answer (score 2):

One more method without graphs is by using `IntegerPartition`.

### Method in brief

---

For this particular problem there are **7** trips from start to end and let $t_1$ to $t_7$ represent those time. All $t_i \in \{1,3,6,8,12\}$.

Let $t_f$ be the total time. Then $t_f$ must partitions into 7 integers all of which belong to  $\{1,3,6,8,12\}$.

If $t_f$ happens to be 30 then the result of

```
 IntegerPartitions[30, {7}, {1, 3, 6, 8, 12}]
```

including all its `Permutations` will contain the time of the successful journey.
So the idea is to go over all permutations of these time and select only the ones which can fit the initial condition.

---

### Mathematica Part

```
split2Bytime[list_, time_] := 
  Module[{p1, p2, p3, p4, flag = 1, trip, pos, onwardPart, returnPart},
  onwardPart = list[[3]];
  returnPart = Last@list;
  Which[Not@MemberQ[onwardPart, First@time], flag = 0, True,
  Which[First@time == First@onwardPart, flag = 0, True,
  pos = Flatten@Position[onwardPart, First@time];
  p2 = onwardPart[[First@pos - 1 ;; First@pos]];
  p3 = Reverse@TakeDrop[onwardPart, {First@pos - 1, First@pos}];
  p4 = PadRight[Last@p3, Length[Last@p3] + Length@returnPart, returnPart];
  trip[1] = Join[{First@p3}, {p4}];
  Which[Not@DuplicateFreeQ[time], 
   p3 = Reverse@TakeDrop[onwardPart, {First@pos - 1}];
   p4 = PadRight[Last@p3, Length[Last@p3] + Length@returnPart,returnPart];
   trip[2] = Join[{First@p3}, {p4}];, True, 
   Which[Not@MemberQ[Last@trip[1], Last@time], flag = 0, True, 
    p3 = Insert[First@trip[1], Last@time, 1];
    p4 = DeleteCases[Last@trip[1], Last@time];
    trip[2] = Join[{p3, p4}];]]
  ];
];

If[flag == 1, Flatten[Array[trip, 2], 1], "failed"]

];
```

The function `split2Bytime` takes the initial `list` and two `time` values and throws the allowed configuration based on that time.

For e.g.

```
split2Bytime[{{}, {}, {1, 3, 6, 8, 12}, {}}, {2, 3}]
(*failed*)
```

will return `failed` because the time argument i.e. `{2,3}` represents the time taken for the first and second trip. But the first trip cannot take 2 units with
`{{}, {}, {1, 3, 6, 8, 12}, {}}` as the initial conflagration.

```
split2Bytime[{{}, {}, {1, 3, 6, 8, 12}, {}}, {3, 3}]
(*{{6, 8, 12}, {1, 3}, {3, 6, 8, 12}, {1}}*)
```

The above e.g. works because `{3,3}` is possible. The result is displayed as four sub-list where the first two part i.e. `{6, 8, 12}, {1, 3}` means `{1,3}` goes to the other side taking `3` seconds and the last two parts `{3, 6, 8, 12}, {1}` means that `{3}` comes back taking `3` seconds again.

```
splitAll[timings_] := 
Module[{flag = 1, last, trip, nlist = {{}, {}, {1, 3, 6, 8, 12}, {}}},
trip[1] = split2Bytime[nlist, timings[[1 ;; 2]]] // Quiet;
trip[2] = split2Bytime[trip[1], timings[[3 ;; 4]]] // Quiet;
trip[3] = split2Bytime[trip[2], timings[[5 ;; 6]]] // Quiet;
last = trip[3][[3]];
If[Not[Max@last == Last@timings] || 
Not[MemberQ[last, Last@timings]], flag = 0];
If[flag == 1, Array[trip, 3], "failed"]]
```

`splitAll` applies `split2Bytime` to all the timings 2 at a time and clubs them  together at the end.

Now we can check for any total time $t_f$ whose integer partitions plus all its permutations satisfies `splitAll`.

```
check[n_] := 
Module[{sol, perms}, 
sol = IntegerPartitions[n, {7}, {1, 3, 6, 8, 12}];
perms = 
Partition[
Flatten[Table[Permutations[sol[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[sol]}]], 7];
DeleteCases[
Table[If[
  Not[ContainsAny[{splitAll[perms[[i]]]}, {"failed"}] || 
    ContainsAny[splitAll[perms[[i]]], {"failed"}]], Sow[i]] // 
 Quiet, {i, 1, Length[perms]}], Null]]
```

`check` checks for all those `Permutations` which results in a failure. We can use it to see which ones are working. Lets check from `20` to `30`

```
DeleteCases[Table[If[Not[check[n] == {}], Sow[n]], {n, 20, 30}], Null]
(*29*)
```

We get the correct total time $t_f=29$.

Now that we now $t_f=29$ we can display the full result of `splitAll`.

```
showResult[n_] := 
Module[{sol, result, perms, res, start = {{1, 3, 6, 8, 12}, {}}},
sol = IntegerPartitions[n, {7}, {1, 3, 6, 8, 12}];
perms = 
Partition[
Flatten[Table[Permutations[sol[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[sol]}]], 7];
res = DeleteCases[
Table[If[
   Not[ContainsAny[{splitAll[perms[[i]]]}, {"failed"}] || 
     ContainsAny[splitAll[perms[[i]]], {"failed"}]], Sow[i]] // 
  Quiet, {i, 1, Length[perms]}], Null];
 result[i_] := 
 Partition[
 Flatten[Append[Prepend[splitAll[perms[[res[[i]]]]], start], 
  Reverse@start], 1], 2];
  Row[Table[Grid[result[i], Frame -> All], {i, 1, Length[res]}], " "]
  ]
```

[image]