# How to repeat the nonblank string?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

As the title, if I have a list:

```
{"", "", "", "2$70", ""}
```

I will expect:

```
{"", "", "", "2$70", "2$70"}
```

If I have

```
{"", "", "", "3$71", "", "2$72", ""}
```

then:

```
{"", "", "", "3$71", "3$71", "2$72", "2$72"}
```

And

```
{"", "", "", "3$71", "","", "2$72", ""}
```

should give

```
{"", "", "", "3$71", "3$71", "", "2$72", "2$72"}
```

This is my try:

```
{"", "", "", "2$70", ""} /. {p : Except["", String], ""} :> {p, p}
```

But I don't know why it doesn't work. Poor ability of  pattern match. Can anybody give some advice?

Comment: most probably a duplicate but hard to find it. here is one way: `Module[{last = "", f},
   f[""] := last;
   f[x_] := last = x;
   f /@ #
   ] &@{"", "", "", "2$70", ""}`

Comment: @Kuba Can you give a pattern matching method for it?

Comment: What you do expect as output for `{"", "x", "y", "", "z", ""}` ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `{"", "x", "y", "y", "z", "z"}`

Comment: Related: [(23454)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23454/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I presently interpret the question

(Now with refinements after considering Chris Degnen's simultaneous answer)

```
fn[list_] :=
  Partition[list, 2, 1, -1, ""] // Cases[{p_, ""} | {_, p_} :> p]
```

Test:

```
 {"", "x", "y", "", "z", ""} // fn
```

> ```
> {"", "x", "y", "y", "z", "z"}
> ```

### Patterns

Since you seem only to be interested in a pattern-matching solution here is my proposal to *avoid* the extremely slow use of [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) while still using pattern-matching as the core of the operation.

```
fn2[list_] :=
  list // ReplacePart @ 
   ReplaceList[list, {a___, p_, "", ___} :> (2 + Length@{a} -> p)]
```

### Recursive replacement

I just realized that this is a perfect time to use a self-referential replacement:

```
fn3[list_] :=
  list /. {a___, p_, "", b___} :> {a, p, p, ##& @@ fn3@{b}}
```

### Benchmark

All three methods are much faster than kglr's `foo` (note the log-log scale).

Now with Carl Woll's `fc`, the fastest method yet. ( but no patterns ;-) )

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

$RecursionLimit = 1*^5;

BenchmarkPlot[{foo, fn, fn2, fn3, fc},
  RandomChoice[{"", "", "", "a", "b"}, #] &
]
```

[image]

Comment: The pattern matching method is slower in generally.

Comment: @yode Indeed it can be, but the main issue here is the use of a single-pass method versus `//.` which has to reprocess the entire list for every element to be duplicated.

Comment: @yode Please see my update.

Comment: Funny~the `ReplaceList` is a good lesson.Upvote! :)

Comment: @yode I added a third and final method to this answer.  If it is not enough to wrest the Accept from kglr's grasp I give up.

Comment: Wow,I have to say that flash my eyes(the last method).

Answer (score 8):

In place modification of a list works well here:

```
fc[list_] := Module[{out=list},
    With[{empty = Pick[Range[2,Length@list], Rest@list,""]},
        out[[empty]]=out[[empty-1]]
    ];
    out
]
```

A comparison with Mr Wizard's fn:

```
data = RandomChoice[{"","","","a","b"}, 10^5];
r1 = fn[data]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = fc[data]; //AbsoluteTiming
r1 === r2
```

> {0.049858,Null}
>
> {0.01092,Null}
>
> True

Comment: Now I feel silly yet again. +1 of course. :^)

Comment: Added to my benchmark.

Comment: haha i tried using a method i thought and i got 67 seconds on my tablet. That really shows how important is being able to write a clear and fast code

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

```
foo = # //. {a___, p : Except["", _String], Longest[b : "" ..],   c___} :>
   {a, p, p, ## & @@ ConstantArray["☺", Length[{b}] - 1], c} /. "☺" -> "" &;

{"", "", "", "3$71", "", "", "2$72", "", "", "", ""} // foo
```

> `{"", "", "", "3$71", "3$71", "", "2$72", "2$72", "", "", ""}`

**Previous post:**

```
rule = {a___, p : Except["", _String], Longest["" ..],  b___} :> {a, p, p, b};

{"", "", "", "3$71", "", "", "2$72", "", "", "", ""} //. rule
```

> `{"", "", "", "3$71", "3$71", "2$72", "2$72"}`

Comment: Thanks very much.But `{"", "", "", "3$71", "", "", "2$72", ""}` will give three `"3$71"`.I just expect two here.

Comment: @yode, fixed...

Comment: I'm sorry,I expect two `"3$71"` but not three.

Comment: @yode, hope i finally got it.

Comment: `{"", "", "", "3$71", "","", "2$72", ""}` should give `{"", "", "", "3$71", "3$71", "", "2$72", "2$72"}`.I'm sorry,actually your code have given me enough information now. :)

Comment: @yode This will have to scan the list multiple times which can be very slow.  I would use `Sequence` instead; see my answer please.

Comment: @yode No *am I wrong, yet again*.  If I don't improve my reading comprehension I'm going to quit Stack Exchange. <:(

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The culprit is my ability of presentation. :)

Answer (score 4):

Borrowing kglr's pattern

```
x = {"", "", "1$71", "3$71", "", "", "2$72", "", "", "", ""};

Prepend[
 Map[Last, Partition[x, 2, 1] /. {p : Except[""], ""} :> {p, p}],
 First[x]]
```

> {"", "", "1\$71", "3\$71", "3\$71", "", "2\$72", "2\$72", "", "", ""}

user might consider to use `Apply` rather than `Map`:

```
Last@@@(Partition[x, 2, 1] /. {p : Except[""], ""} :> {p, p})//Prepend[First@x]
```

Comment: I was just posting a `Partition` method myself.  +1 and I hope I don't step on any toes.

Comment: No worries. :-)

Comment: @ChrisDegnen @Mr.Wizard what if you use `Last@@@ .... ` instead of `Map[Last ...]` . I assume the former will be faster

Comment: @AliHashmi I avoided `Last` entirely by hard-coding it into `f[{_, x_}] := x`.  For this code I would use `Part[. . ., All, 2]` as that is usually fastest.

Comment: @AliHashmi Since you care about refinements I realized that this code could be made shorter; see my updated answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard i like how the post started and where it ended !

Answer (score 3):

Using `SequenceReplace` (new in 11.3)

```
f = SequenceReplace[{a : Except[""], ""} :> Sequence[a, a]] @ #&;

f @ {"", "", "", "270", ""}
```

{"", "", "", "270", "270"}

```
f @ {"", "", "", "371", "", "272", ""}
```

{"", "", "", "371", "371", "272", "272"}

```
f @ {"", "", "", "371", "", "", "272", ""}
```

{"", "", "", "371", "371", "", "272", "272"}

**Addendum**

As Syed commented a better solution would be

```
f = SequenceReplace[{a_String, ""} :> Sequence[a, a]] @ #&;

f @ {"", "", "", "270", ""}
```

{"", "", "", "270", "270"}

Comment: This works, albeit it is making redundant substitutions by not checking for empty strings: `SequenceReplace[list, {a_String, ""} :> Sequence[a, a]]` where `list` is your input.

Comment: Thanks, Syed, I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Using `SequenceSplit`:

```
sp[lst_] := SequenceSplit[lst, s : {Except[""], ""} :> s]

pos1 = Position[sp[l1], {a_String, _} /; DigitQ[a]];

Flatten@ReplacePart[sp[l1], Thread[pos1 -> Cases[sp[l1], {a_, _} :> {a, a}]]]

(*{"", "", "", "270", "270"}*)

pos2 = Position[sp[l2], {a_String, _} /; DigitQ[a]];

Flatten@ReplacePart[sp[l2], Thread[pos2 -> Cases[sp[l2], {a_, _} :> {a, a}]]]

(*{"", "", "", "371", "371", "272", "272"}*)

pos3 = Position[sp[l3], {a_String, _} /; DigitQ[a]];

Flatten@ReplacePart[sp[l3], Thread[pos3 -> Cases[sp[l3], {a_, _} :> {a, a}]]]

(*{"", "", "", "371", "371", "", "272", "272"}*)
```